# Heap Dump total Retained Heap < JVM Max memory and still OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I've been getting some OutOfMemoryExceptions recently in my JVM, and have decided to start analyzing my heap dumps using MAT to see if I can pinpoint what threads are consuming the majority of my memory.

Interestingly enough, I am looking at all the threads in the system and see that the total retained heap for all threads is about 4.8G.  However, my max heap size for my JVM is set to 10G.  I can correlate that my heap dump is a 10G file.

How is that possible?  Wouldn't my total retained size need to be approaching the 10G limit to be generating OOMs?  Am I misinterpreting something here?

According to the Overview tab:

```
Size: 6.6 GB Classes: 15.7k Objects: 164.1m Class Loader: 690
```

The exact error message is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at business.service.AuditImportHelper.importAuditStream(AuditImportHelper.java:580)
    at business.service.AuditImportHelper.importAuditTrailFiles(AuditImportHelper.java:372)
    at business.service.AuditImportHelper.doImport(AuditImportHelper.java:171)
    ....
    ....
    ....
    at org.jboss.mq.SpyMessageConsumer.addMessage(SpyMessageConsumer.java:170)
    at org.jboss.mq.SpySession.run(SpySession.java:323)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsServerSession.run(JmsServerSession.java:237)
    at org.jboss.resource.work.WorkWrapper.execute(WorkWrapper.java:204)
    at org.jboss.util.threadpool.BasicTaskWrapper.run(BasicTaskWrapper.java:275)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(PooledExecutor.java:743)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:535)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:322)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:363)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at business.service.AuditImportHelper.importAuditStream(AuditImportHelper.java:457)
    at business.service.AuditImportHelper.importAuditTrailFiles(AuditImportHelper.java:372)
```

I can see in my heap dump that the array it is trying to copy (char[]) is fairly large (1G).  Does the JVM preallocate the entire space when trying to do the `copyOf` or is it done on an element-per-element basis?

I'm trying to what parameters are passed to the `copyOf()` method, but not sure if/how to see those in MAT.  Is there a way to see the parameters of the method being called in MAT in the thread view, or other?

Comment: Can you please share some stats ? Or the way you are  calculating memory?

Comment: @YatiSawhney I didn't do any stats analysis.  I just opened MAT, listed all java threads and calculated the precise retained heap.   At the bottom of the thread listing, it gives the total retained heap, which is significantly less than the full heap size.  Which is what I find confusing.

Comment: Is your JVM running in a container?

Comment: @Henry No - it's a plain JDK7 JVM executing in a Windows environment.  Nothing particularly special about it.  It's actually a JBoss4 application server with a 10G of heap space defined.

Comment: Can you please provide the actual error message that you get?

Comment: I believe you have checked if memory needed for your application is actually available at that very time. Since windows is the underlying OS check your task manager processes to see if memory is actually available. OS will allocate that specified block(which your are setting ) for your process only if its available at that time. Please ensure the same

Comment: GC roots are not limited to threads. Static fields and JNI references may also hold a graph of live objects.

Comment: @ErichSchreiner Stack trace & error message provided.  Some additional insight added as well.

Comment: @apangin Interesting - I didn't think of Static fields.  Do you know how/where I can see those in MAT?

Comment: @EricB. Just list all ClassLoaders and/or classes.

Comment: *Of course*, trying to copy an array requires allocating the entire target array’s memory at once. Did you ever hear of an array resizing feature in Java? Besides that, calculating the retained size *is* imprecise. It calculates the semantically used memory, but has no clue about the impacts of object alignment and padding. AFAIK, heap dumps don’t even tell you how big references (32 bit or 64 bit) are…

Comment: @Holger - good point.  I have my head so focused on searching for my "missing" memory, didn't realize that.  That gives me some additional clues, but still doesn't explain why I'm throwing OOM errors.